# Python: How to check if a signed number is positive or negative or none?

Tags: python, numbers

Simply, I am entering a value, I want to determine whether the value is alpha or not. If it is not alpha, I want to check if it is a number or not. If it is a number I want to check if it is positive or negative.

I read a lot about checking a signed number like `-50`. There are two ways, we can use something like this:

```
try:
   val = int(x)
except ValueError:
   print("That's not an int!")
```

Which I think I do not need it here and I do not know where to put it in my code.

The other way is to use `.lstrip("-+")`, but it is not working.

```
amount = 0
while True:
    amount = input("Enter your amount ===> ")
    if amount.isalpha() or amount.isspace() or amount == "":
        print("Please enter only a number without spaces")
    elif amount.lstrip("-+").isdigit():
        if int(amount) < 0:
            print("You entered a negative number")
        elif int(amount) > 6:
            print("You entered a very large number")
        else:
            print(" Why I am always being printed ?? ")
    else:
        print("Do not enter alnum data")
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: consider removing python 2.7 tag since you are using version 3.

Comment: This is working for me as it is, BTW.

Comment: Also works for me like a charm.

Comment: I do not think the [tag:python-3.x] tag is needed here, because this question is not version-specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how you would integrate a `try`/`except` block:

```
amount = 0
while True:
    amount = input("Hit me with your best num!")
    try:
        amount = int(amount)
        if amount < 0:
            print("That number is too tiny!")
        elif amount > 6:
            print("That number is yuge!")
        else:
            print("what a boring number, but I'll take it")
            break  # How you exit this loop
    except ValueError:
        print("Wow dude, that's like not even a number")
```

It does all the heavy lifting for you, as `int()` can process numbers with `+`/`-` automatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> amount = '-6'
>>> '-' in amount
True
>>> amount = amount.strip('-')
>>> amount.isdigit()
True
```

Comment: Working with strings when you can convert it to numbers is nearly always a bad idea. I don't see why not cast it to a number (float/int) before and then checking whether it's smaller/greater than zero.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the number is less than 0 or greater than 0 with `< >`

Comment: This is not helpful as OP did exactly that in his example, but his problem was more that he wasn't able to convert the string into a number for that.